# How to display a date facet in a date popup/picker?

Tags: 8, search

I have a date range field in my content type.

Is there any way to display a date popup/picker facet on my search page.

Any workaround? through facet api, javascript etc?

Because I have searched all the issues of facets module but nothing found any helpful.

Comment: I can’t speak to Facets specifically, but there is a core issue about this. It is a surprisingly difficult problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the following way.

Created a custom form with date popup fields.

Displays it on the search page and hide the actual facet which is in links.

Then through javascript, I used the actual facets with the values from the date popup fields.